# Getting ClassCastException while running faces portlet in Websphere portal server

Tags: portlet, websphere-portal, jsr168

I am getting following exception while running JSF based portlet in websphere portal environment, version 6.1.

```
 ---- Begin backtrace for Nested Throwables
javax.portlet.PortletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletConfigWrapper
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:369)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:82)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.rrd.RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.doDispatch(RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.java:60)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheCollaborator.doDispatch(CacheCollaborator.java:74)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
        at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.doDispatch(PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.java:121)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.dispatch(PortletServlet.java:208)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:165)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1213)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1154)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:848)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:691)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:654)
        at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:526)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:673)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:235)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:78)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.PortletInvokerCacheCollaborator.doRender(PortletInvokerCacheCollaborator.java:58)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.invoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:313)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doInvoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:101)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.invokePMI(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:163)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doInvoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:91)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doRender(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:74)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.render(PortletInvokerImpl.java:97)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerImpl.doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:119)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:80)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.ExtCollaborator.doRender(ExtCollaborator.java:71)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheInvokerCollaborator.doRender(CacheInvokerCollaborator.java:66)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:89)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.pcinvoker.PortletInvokerImpl$2.run(PortletInvokerImpl.java:100)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.pcinvoker.PortletInvokerImpl.invokeRender(PortletInvokerImpl.java:96)
        at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl$1.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:92)
        at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:175)
        at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invokeRender(PortletInvokerImpl.java:90)
        at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:116)
        at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.PortletContainerImpl.doRenderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:641)
        at com.ibm.wps.pe.ext.render.AbstractRenderManager.performService(AbstractRenderManager.java:264)
        at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:132)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.tags.PortletRenderTag.doStartTag(PortletRenderTag.java:179)
        at com.ibm._jsp._Control._jspx_meth_wps_portletRender_0(_Control.java:204)
        at com.ibm._jsp._Control._jspx_meth_wps_if_0(_Control.java:245)
        at com.ibm._jsp._Control._jspService(_Control.java:98)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:88)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1213)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1154)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:848)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:691)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:654)
        at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:526)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:248)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:673)
        at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.handleRequest(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:93)
        at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.include(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:53)
        at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:50)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.skins.Default.render(Default.java:154)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.SkinTemplate.render(SkinTemplate.java:68)
        at com.ibm.wps.composition.elements.Component.render(Component.java:638)
        at com.ibm.wps.composition.elements.Control.render(Control.java:159)
        at com.ibm.wps.composition.Composition.render(Composition.java:3082)
        at com.ibm.wps.composition.Composition.render(Composition.java:159)
        at com.ibm.websphere.personalization.transformation.PznTransformationLayoutModel.render(PznTransformationLayoutModel.java:90)
        at com.ibm.wps.model.wrappers.LayoutModelWrapperFactoryImpl$LayoutModelWrapperImpl.render(LayoutModelWrapperFactoryImpl.java:275)
        at com.ibm.wps.model.ModelUtil$WrappedCompositionModel.render(ModelUtil.java:1127)
        at com.ibm._jsp._UnlayeredContainer_2D_V._jspService(_UnlayeredContainer_2D_V.java:93)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:88)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1213)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1154)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:848)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:691)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:654)
        at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:526)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:248)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:673)
        at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.handleRequest(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:93)
        at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.include(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:53)
        at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:50)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.skins.Default.render(Default.java:154)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.SkinTemplate.render(SkinTemplate.java:68)
        at com.ibm.wps.composition.elements.Component.render(Component.java:638)
        at com.ibm.wps.composition.Composition.render(Composition.java:3082)
        at com.ibm.wps.composition.Composition.render(Composition.java:159)
        at com.ibm.websphere.personalization.transformation.PznTransformationLayoutModel.render(PznTransformationLayoutModel.java:90)
        at com.ibm.wps.model.wrappers.LayoutModelWrapperFactoryImpl$LayoutModelWrapperImpl.render(LayoutModelWrapperFactoryImpl.java:275)
        at com.ibm.wps.model.ModelUtil$WrappedCompositionModel.render(ModelUtil.java:1127)
        at com.ibm._jsp._UnlayeredContainer_2D_H._jspService(_UnlayeredContainer_2D_H.java:112)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:88)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1213)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1154)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:848)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:691)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:654)
        at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:526)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:248)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:673)
        at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.handleRequest(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:93)
        at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.include(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:53)
        at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:50)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.skins.Default.render(Default.java:154)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.SkinTemplate.render(SkinTemplate.java:68)
        at com.ibm.wps.composition.elements.Component.render(Component.java:638)
        at com.ibm.wps.composition.Composition.render(Composition.java:3082)
        at com.ibm.wps.composition.Composition.render(Composition.java:159)
        at com.ibm.websphere.personalization.transformation.PznTransformationLayoutModel.render(PznTransformationLayoutModel.java:90)
        at com.ibm.wps.model.wrappers.LayoutModelWrapperFactoryImpl$LayoutModelWrapperImpl.render(LayoutModelWrapperFactoryImpl.java:275)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.tags2.PageRenderTag.doStartTag(PageRenderTag.java:534)
        at com.ibm._jsp._Home._jspx_meth_wps_pageRender_0(_Home.java:177)
        at com.ibm._jsp._Home._jspService(_Home.java:92)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:88)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1213)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1154)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:848)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:691)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:654)
        at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:526)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:248)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:673)
        at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.handleRequest(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:93)
        at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.include(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:53)
        at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:58)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.screens.Default.render(Default.java:96)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.ScreenTemplate.render(ScreenTemplate.java:59)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.tags2.ScreenRenderTag.doStartTag(ScreenRenderTag.java:182)
        at com.ibm._jsp._Default._jspx_meth_wps_screenRender_0(_Default.java:2505)
        at com.ibm._jsp._Default._jspService(_Default.java:2035)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:88)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1213)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1154)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:848)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:691)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:654)
        at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:526)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:248)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:673)
        at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.handleRequest(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:93)
        at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.include(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:53)
        at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:50)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.themes.Default.doDispatch(Default.java:294)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.themes.Default.render(Default.java:247)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.ThemeTemplate.render(ThemeTemplate.java:65)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPRenderPhase.processRendering(WPRenderPhase.java:509)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPBaseRenderPhase.execute(WPBaseRenderPhase.java:194)
        at com.ibm.wps.state.phases.AbstractRenderPhase.next(AbstractRenderPhase.java:106)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPAbstractRenderPhase.next(WPAbstractRenderPhase.java:97)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.callPortal(Servlet.java:860)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doFilter(Servlet.java:1257)
        at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.ContentHandlerCleanup.doFilter(ContentHandlerCleanup.java:648)
        at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:93)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.service(Servlet.java:1248)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1213)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1154)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:145)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtendedLocaleFilter.doFilter(ExtendedLocaleFilter.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
        at com.ibm.wps.resolver.friendly.servlet.FriendlySelectionFilter.doFilter(FriendlySelectionFilter.java:191)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
        at com.ibm.wps.mappingurl.impl.URLAnalyzer.doFilter(URLAnalyzer.java:352)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.VirtualPortalFilter.doFilter(VirtualPortalFilter.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
        at com.ibm.wps.state.filter.StateCleanup.doFilter(StateCleanup.java:94)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:848)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:691)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:654)
        at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:526)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:90)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:764)
        at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:133)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:457)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:300)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:102)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:556)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:606)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:979)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1064)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1593)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletConfigWrapper
        at com.ibm.faces.context.MultipartFacesContextFactoryImpl.getFacesContext(MultipartFacesContextFactoryImpl.java:85)
        at com.ibm.faces.webapp.FacesGenericPortlet.getFacesContext(FacesGenericPortlet.java:616)
        at com.ibm.faces.webapp.FacesGenericPortlet.doRender(FacesGenericPortlet.java:343)
        at com.ibm.faces.webapp.FacesGenericPortlet.doView(FacesGenericPortlet.java:391)
        at com.acs.hris.ccp.customercare.portlets.CCPChangePasswordPortlet.doView(CCPChangePasswordPortlet.java:101)
        at com.ibm.faces.webapp.FacesGenericPortlet.doDispatch(FacesGenericPortlet.java:292)
        at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:128)
        at com.ibm.wps.propertybroker.standard.filter.C2APortletFilter.doFilter(C2APortletFilter.java:183)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:120)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:573)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.rrd.RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.doRender(RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheCollaborator.doRender(CacheCollaborator.java:92)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
        at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.doRender(PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.java:156)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:273)
        ... 216 more
```

My portlet extends FacesGenericPortlet and have a simple doView() method.

Has anybody experienced this kind of exception ever?

yes i am using following jars beside jsf-portlet.jar (and not jsf-portletbridge.jar)

1. commons-beanutils
2. commons-collections
3. commons-digester
4. icu4j_3_4_1
5. jsf-api
6. jsf-ibm
7. jsf-impl
8. jstl
9. jstl_el
10. standard

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace - nothing is this short on WPS.  Also, it sounds as if it could be a classloader issue - do you have any IBM jars (besides jsf-portletbridge) in your portlet's web-inf/lib dir?

Comment: Thanks scotth for replying.. I have updated the question with details you asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what version of RAD you're using, but if you're on 7 or higher, it is recommended to use a newer set of jsf portlet bridge libraries.

According to http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21307687 (which documents a different problem related to the portlet bridge):

> The class com.ibm.faces.webapp.FacesGenericPortlet is the portlet class used as a base class for RAD v6.0 JSF portlets.
>
> In RAD v7.0, the portlet bridge can cope better with browser Back button issues and to pass information between action to render phase without using the session. As a result, a new .jar file jsf-portletbridge.jar replaces old RAD v6.0 portlet bridge jsf-portlet.jar.
>
> This particular problem occurs when the new .jar file jsf-portletbridge.jar is used but code for the portlet classes was not updated as described in the Help entry Updating Faces runtime resources for portlet projects from V6.0.x.

According to the RAD7 InfoCenter, you'll want to remove most of the JSF portlet jars you have listed and [use the ones that ship with RAD7](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.rad.migration.doc/topics/tmgv6portletjsfto601.html).  I could be wrong but I believe the jsf-portletbridge.jar is available somewhere in the portal installation too.

Are you able to use RAD7 or higher?

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Replacing jsf-portlet with jsf-portletbridge worked!!